# Adjust bounty auto giving

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, bounty

So in a question it had a 500 bounty. However when the timer expired no answer was chosen. The answer with the most up votes is not the best answer (this is not me trying to get the bounty from him). Several other people spent more time answering and had similar answers but were more finished. Perhaps instead of auto awarding the bounty a mod could step in and select an answer that appears to fix the problem and is high quality. [Android Studio doesnt recognize my device - Nexus 6P](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35249422/android-studio-doesnt-recognize-my-device-nexus-6p/38862161#38862161)

Comment: We only have a handful of mods. What if the bounty is on a question none of them have any sort of experience or knowledge with?

Comment: You didn't win the lottery, the winner buys more tickets.  Go for the 50s to warm up.

Comment: you could blame the OP for letting the bounty expire like that. a bounty is awarded either by at the end of the bounty period automatically (only awarding half) or the OP select's an answer themselves. when the OP lets it's it expire they give up the bounty to the whims of the community who can be [very fickle](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215379/should-drive-by-downvoting-be-more-effectively-caught/215397#215397)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just as moderators can't accept answers, they cannot award bounties nor should they.  The bounty system is in place so users can draw attention to a question, reward existing answers, etc.  It's up to the user placing the bounty to award it, not a moderator.

Asking a moderator to award it, assumes they are knowledgeable enough to judge the best answer, that's not the purpose of our moderators.  They are [human exception handlers](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/) and awarding a bounty doesn't fall into that definition.

If the user placing the bounty doesn't manually award it, the bounty is cut in half and awarded to an answer based on score. If you have a competing answer on a bounty post that you don't believe is helpful, then I'd recommend using your downvote. In this particular case there have been no downvotes against the answer you feel didn't deserve the bounty award, so there was no signal to anyone else that the answer wasn't the best.

Comment: I did not know that down voting an answer since I did not think it should be ahead of better answers... Thanks!

Comment: So be getting 11 down votes annoys me. According to the down vote button it should show little or no effort and is low quality unclear or not useful.

Comment: @ChristopherPeart [Voting on Meta is different](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta), downvotes here typically mean users disagree with a request. In this case, they most likely don't agree that mods should award bounties.